# MySQL | index FULLTEXT vs index PRIMARY KEY used in a WHERE like Query

Tags: mysql, performance, select, indexing, full-text-search

## Problem

Having a table which has a primary key as `varchar` and is used for looking up the with `WHERE column like 'some_string%'` against a huge amount of data (millions) and huge amount of requests (1000 per seconds) I need to improve the performance of such query

## Questions

- Would that primary key column work better if is **also** a index of type `FULLTEXT`?
- Is there a faster way to look up records giving the below scenario, or that is good as it gets?

***NOTE:***
It has been pointed out in the comment section:
"Why don't you try it out and see whether you get any performance gain?"

Which I will eventually try it out as well offcourse, but the objective of the quesiton (and asking In StackOverflow) is not just 'would this run faster'?
But also have some other opinion with experience in the subject, that may tell me whether is usefull, wont do any changes, dangerous, a better way etc..?

To run actual test and benchmark there are many factors and is very time consuming, hopefully someone that knows by heart the answer will tell. In order to truly test something over performance, especially on this nature, you need to test it in different environment, with a lot of test data and test different scenario. Is not enough to test it locally, **you may get false result for whatever reason or this may cause issue in the future that I am not aware of**

## Scenario

Giving this table

```sql
create table book
(
    title       varchar(100)                       not null,
    author      varchar(20)                        not null,   
    created     datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
    primary key (title, author)
);
```

And we insert some test data

```sql
insert into book (author, title) values
    ('JohnDoe', 'bookSummer_1'),
    ('JohnDoe', 'bookSummer_2'),
    ('JohnDoe', 'bookSummer_3'),
    ('JohnDoe', 'bookSummer_4'),
    ('JohnDoe', 'bookWinder_1'),
    ('JohnDoe', 'bookWinder_2'),
    ('JohnDoe', 'bookWinder_3'),
    ('JohnDoe', 'bookWinder_4')
```

Then, we grab the title books by its prefix as so

```sql
SELECT author, title from book WHERE author='JohnDoe' and title like 'bookSummer_%';
```

Now, imagine that 1 author has millions of millions of different books, we the title prefix may be as longs as 100 chars. As you can see, the `title` column is already a `PRIMARY KEY`
Would add the column `title` an additional index of type `FULLTEXT` be beneficial (and probably change the query?

So I mean add as so

```sql
ALTER TABLE book ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `title_fulltext_index` (`title`);
```

Comment: Why don't you try it out and see whether you get any performance gain?

Comment: Well, there are many factors and is very time consuming, that's why I am asking here in the first place, else what's StackOverflow for if not asking and hopefully someone that knows by heart the answer will tell. In order to truly test something over performance, especially on this nature, you need to test it in different environment, with a lot of test data and test different scenario. Is not enough to test it locally, you may get false result for whatever reason.

Comment: @Shadow if the vote down was for the reason you are asking 'why don't you try it out' I believe is not deserved. Is a well structure question, and someone may actually know the answer without run test. Why? Well, some stuff you know that will just run better by experience. Hence I am asking someone with experience with FULLTEXT index vs Primary Key

Comment: @Shadow I mean ,I will eventually try it out as well offcourse. but the objective of the quesiton is not just 'would this run faster'? But also have some other opinion with experience in the subject, that may tell me whether is usefull, wont do any changes, dangerours, a better way etc..? Be open minded my friend :) I updated the question so taht is more clear this as well

Comment: The problem is with optimisation questions like yours is that you are seeking answers to a specific problem that no one else can reproduce but you as we do not have your data, we do not know all queries that you are running, and we do not know your business requirements! Fulltext index and search is not a like-for-like replacement for a standard index. You are not going to get the same results back as with a like search. Please see https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: @Shadow the query that I am running are basically the same as above, and the business logic too. The quesiton is simple really there is no reason to put other things like business requirements. I am asking from a pure, SQL perspective.

Comment: @Shadow is the same as, for example python. I do *by heart* thata dictionary lookup will run faster than a list lookup. So if someone is asking in here about that with less experience in Python I would be able to answer.I don't need to know no business requirements or anything else. ALl the information needed is in the question.

Comment: Business requirements do matter as your code has to satisfy business requirements. Your comparison with list or dictionary look ups is not particularly great because both will give you the same answer, while a normal index and fulltext index will not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your specific query, e.g. a prefix-search (`like 'somestring%'`), a fulltext index makes no sense.

A fulltext index can improve performance if you look for words in the middle of a sentence, e.g. `'some text somestring'`. A normal index will not index `somestring`, so to find it, you will have to look through the whole table. A fulltext index will index every word, so you can find `'some'`, `'text'` and `'somestring'` with a (fast) index lookup.

And there are some additional steps involved: a fulltext index cannot be used together with another index, so if you find the title and want to verify that the author matches, you have to read the actual row from the table.

If you instead look up the title with the primary key, you already read the row from the table (as reading the primary key means reading the table, at least for InnoDB), so you are already there.

It's hard to even come up with theoretical scenarios where a fulltext index would be faster for your situation. One situation might be if your table is really large, preferably too large to fit into memory, while the fulltext index is small and can be kept in cache, and you look for an entry that is not there. Then the fulltext index can give you the answer without slow disk reads. But even then, there are probably better ways to improve your setup.

#### Optimal index for your query (Multiple-Part Indexes)

By the way, **the optimal index for your query** based on your `SELECT` query ->  `where author = 'string' and title like 'otherstring%'` is this index:

```sql
PRIMARY KEY (author, title)
```

And not

```sql
PRIMARY KEY (title, author)
```

Because has the columns in a different order than in your primary key.

This is because **[the index lookup cannot use the second column anymore when you use the first column for a partial match](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html#range-access-multi-part)**, but it can use both columns if the comparison on the first column is "=".

#### Imagine e.g. :

Giving a Phone book an a `SELECT` query like:

```sql
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM phone_book 
WHERE first_name = 'Federico' AND last_name LIKE 'B%'
```

- If `PRIMARY KEY` index is: `(last_name, first_name)`

If I asked you to find everyone with the `first_name` "Federico" and a `last_name` like "B%", the **`first_name` doesn't reduce the number of entries** you have to look at you will **read all `first_name`** for entries that start with "B".

- If `PRIMARY KEY` index is: `(first_name, last_name)`

**You can skip** all first names that are not "Federico", and all last names that don't start with "B".

If it makes a difference with your data, and especially if it makes enough difference to be worth the additional resourcesthat the index requires (e.g. disk space, time to update), is something you would have to test though.

Comment: that's the answer I was looking for. Just a small quesiton about what u last wrote "aving the columns in a different order than in your primary key" Are you saying that, the WHERE clause should match the primary key order for maximal performance gain? (PS: By the way good catch, I put it there to see if it got notice and it seems it did! cuz is someting I asked my self before, so it seems that is True)

Comment: @Shadow ☝ This is the answer I was looking for, As an example for you that not all cases related to the post you pssed in the comment >https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/  .AS you can see, Solarflare was able to answer at a glance basically , see the beginning of his answer -> "... a fulltext index makes no sense."

Comment: So, based on a random person's answer you concluded that fulltext index does not make sense for you, without actually trying it out! Well done!

Comment: @FedericoBaù The index order does not have to match the order you listed the columns in the where clause, but you cannot use the 2nd column after you made a partial search in the first column; I elaborated a bit in the answer about it. About your remark towards Shadow: don't disregard his comment, he is right; the answer to "which is faster for me" is "test it". You might have one of those special cases, or I might just be wrong. Nevertheless, in 99.9947% of cases, I would not even consider a fulltext index for your specific query, and I assume that is what you wanted to know.

Comment: @Shadow how do you know I didn't try it out? :) I may or may not but I don't want to give the result to influence the answers as it should be based on their experience. Also you don't know what I concluded. I accept the answer because is exaustive and if the community will find the accepted answer should vote down. By the way " based on a random person's answer" emhh. You just explained how StackOverflow works after all. People that are around the world answer you question , they are "random" just because we dont know them. Eitherway I won't answer no more the comments . cheers 

Comment: The order of the tests in `WHERE` does _not_ matter; the order in the `INDEX` _does_ matter.  Column(s) tested with `=` should come first in the index.  Using a _leading_ wildcard on `LIKE` will invalidate some of the above analysis.